# fetching json data in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, youtube

Json code is:

> `{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"bLBSoC_2IY8","uploaded":"2014-04-         29T04:11:56.000Z","updated":"2014-12-04T16:08:10.000Z","uploader":"latenight","category":"Comedy","title":"Lip Sync Battle with Emma Stone","description":"Jimmy and Emma Stone square off in a lip sync battle and Emma shows she's not afraid of lightning fast lyrics.\n\nSubscribe NOW to The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon: http://bit.ly/1nwT1aN\n\nWatch The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon Weeknights 11:35/10:35c\nGet more Jimmy Fallon: \nFollow Jimmy: http://Twitter.com/JimmyFallon\nLike Jimmy: https://Facebook.com/JimmyFallon\n\nGet more The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon: \nFollow The Tonight Show: http://Twitter.com/FallonTonight\nLike The Tonight Show: https://Facebook.com/FallonTonight\nThe Tonight Show Tumblr: http://fallontonight.tumblr.com/\n\nGet more NBC: \nNBC YouTube: http://bit.ly/1dM1qBH\nLike NBC: http://Facebook.com/NBC\nFollow NBC: http://Twitter.com/NBC\nNBC Tumblr: http://nbctv.tumblr.com/\nNBC Google+: https://plus.google.com/+NBC/posts\n\nThe Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon features hilarious highlights from the show including: comedy sketches, music parodies, celebrity interviews, ridiculous games, and, of course, Jimmy's Thank You Notes and hashtags! You'll also find behind the scenes videos and other great web exclusives.\n\nLip Sync Battle with Emma Stone\nhttp://www.youtube.com/fallontonight","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/bLBSoC_2IY8/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/bLBSoC_2IY8/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLBSoC_2IY8&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"http://m.youtube.com/details?v=bLBSoC_2IY8"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/bLBSoC_2IY8?version=3&f=videos&d=AXyDziqd4CCanEZDalXV_C8O88HsQjpE1a8d1GxQnGDm&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://r7---sn-o097zuek.c.youtube.com/CkULENy73wIaPAmPIfYvoFKwbBMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3NyIQF8g84qneAgmpxGQ2pV1fwvDvPB7EI6RNWvHdRsUJxg5gw=/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://r7---sn-o097zuek.c.youtube.com/CkULENy73wIaPAmPIfYvoFKwbBMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3NyIQF8g84qneAgmpxGQ2pV1fwvDvPB7EI6RNWvHdRsUJxg5gw=/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":446,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":4.9287434,"likeCount":"279315","ratingCount":284381,"viewCount":36983500,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":12125,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"moderated","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}}`

I am trying to fetch data in php array the loop is runing fine but but variable has no values:

```
 foreach ($result->data as $item) {
 $title = is_null($subject) ? htmlentities($item->title) : htmlentities($item->video->title);
 $id = is_null($subject) ? $item->id : $item->video->id;
 $timestamp = is_null($subject) ? strtotime($item->uploaded) : strtotime($item->video->uploaded);
 $uploaded = date('M j, Y', $timestamp);
 $watch = is_null($subject) ? $item->player->default : $item->video->player->default;
 $image = is_null($subject) ? $item->thumbnail->sqDefault : $item->video->thumbnail->sqDefault;
 $description = is_null($subject) ? $item->description : $item->video->description;
 $viewCount = is_null($subject) ? $item->viewCount : $item->video->viewCount;
 $duration = is_null($subject) ? gmdate('H:i:s', intval($item->duration)) : gmdate('H:i:s',        intval($item->video->duration));
echo $id
echo $title
echo $description
?>
```

whats the problem?

Comment: You're supposed to tell us what the problem is, then we help you solve it.

Comment: the problem is that loop is running but title,id,and other variable are not assigned any values

Comment: var_dump $result or $item

Comment: Where is the code where you json_decode the JSON?

Comment: {"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"bLBSoC_2IY8","uploaded":"2014-04-         29T04:11:56.000Z","updated":"2014-12-04T16:08:10.000Z","uploader":"latenight","category":"Comedy","title":"Lip Sync Battle with Emma Stone","description":"Jimmy and Emma Stone square off in a lip sync battle and Emma shows she's not afraid of lightning fast lyrics.\n\nSubscribe NOW to The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon: http://bit.ly/1nwT1aN\n\nWatch The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon Weeknights 11:35/10:35c\nGet more Jimmy Fallon: \nFollow }} like this

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: $result = json_decode($request);

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://eval.in/230441

Comment: Abstract art ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marc_B tried to explain, you need to loop over the key/value pairs like:

```
foreach($result->data as $key=>$value) {
```

And look for the `$key`s you're interested in.

[Here is a working example](https://eval.in/230506)

However, if you data always contains one result, you can skip the loop and just:

```
echo $result->data->id;
echo $result->data->title;
echo $result->data->description;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong obj access path:

```
{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"bLBSoC_2IY8","uploaded":"2014-04-etc..

foreach($obj->data as $item) {
```

is going to give you "blBSoC_2IY8", "2014-04-etc..." as $item, which are just strings. `$item->whatever` is going to fail, since $item is a string, not an object.